# ABP Framework: "ActivatorChain": "Castle.Proxies.InboundDocumentServiceProxy -> RCM.PatientManagement.PatientOptimization.PatientDocumentService"

Tags: .net, angular, api, aspnetboilerplate, abp

*I have two projects Patient and Platform in ABP Framework. An Exception was thrown when calling the DocumentService in Patient in Platform Project InboundDocumentService. But whenever the service in platform get hit the exception given below was thrown.*

[Swagger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L10oc.png)

**Exception:**

2023-01-24 17:24:18.701 +05:30 [ERR] An exception was thrown while activating Castle.Proxies.InboundDocumentServiceProxy -> RCM.PatientManagement.PatientOptimization.PatientDocumentService.
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating Castle.Proxies.InboundDocumentServiceProxy -> RCM.PatientManagement.PatientOptimization.PatientDocumentService.
---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Volo.Abp.Autofac.AbpAutofacConstructorFinder' on type 'RCM.PatientManagement.PatientOptimization.PatientDocumentService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`2[RCM.DropdownManagement.Dropdowns.Entity.Patient.DocumentType,System.Guid] documentTypeRepository' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Volo.Abp.BlobStoring.IBlobContainer`1[RCM.PatientManagement.PatientOptimization.Container.PatientDocuments], Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`2[RCM.PatientManagement.PatientOptimization.PatientPersonal,System.Guid], Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`2[RCM.PatientManagement.PatientOptimization.PatientDataMonitor,System.Guid], Volo.Abp.Guids.IGuidGenerator, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration, Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`2[RCM.PatientManagement.PatientOptimization.PatientDocument,System.Guid], Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`2[RCM.DropdownManagement.Dropdowns.Entity.Patient.DocumentType,System.Guid])'.
at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetAllBindings(ConstructorBinder[] availableConstructors, IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.b__11_0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DisposalTrackingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder`3.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<PropertiesAutowired>b__0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
at Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy.RegistrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass8_0`3.<EnableInterfaceInterceptors>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder`3.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<OnPreparing>b__0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.CoreEventMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ExecuteOperation(ResolveRequest request) at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ServiceBasedControllerActivator.Create(ControllerContext actionContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
2023-01-24 17:24:18.701 +05:30 [ERR] ---------- Exception Data ----------
ActivatorChain = Castle.Proxies.InboundDocumentServiceProxy -> RCM.PatientManagement.PatientOptimization.PatientDocumentService

I tried registering the service in Platform host project.Still it is not working.
I want call the Document Service in Patient Project in Platform Project via Interface.
Anyone Please help